# Changing values of second spinner based on first spinner using switch case and strings

Tags: java, android, xml

UPDATE: I fixed this myself eventually, however answers are useful and helped me figure it out. See end for updated Java.

I know this question has been asked a few times, however the solutions are not working for me and I can't figure out why.. Also many are referring to JSON and I am using string arrays.

Basically I have two spinners, and I want to display specific breeds (second), based on the type of animal selected (first). For example, when Dogs is selected, I want it to show the string array of dog breeds.

I would like to try and do this with a switch case as it seems the most logical to me, and I understand it better, however open to ideas on how I can improve.

Heres what I have - I am getting an error on @Override and the error log isn't much help to me (new to Java):

XML

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/which_spinner"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
    android:labelFor="@id/which_spinner"
    android:text="@string/pet_type"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.504" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/breed_spinner"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
    android:labelFor="@id/breed_spinner"
    android:text="@string/pet_breed"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.583" />
```

Strings

```
<string-array name="pet_type">
    <item>Dog</item>
    <item>Cat</item>
    <item>Rabbit</item>
    <item>Hamster</item>
    <item>Bird</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="dog_breeds">
    <item>Alsatian</item>
    <item>Border Collie</item>
    <item>Labrador</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="cat_breeds">
    <item>Persian</item>
    <item>Hairless</item>
    <item>Tomcat</item>
</string-array>
```

Java (see later for working code)

```
public class Questionnaire extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionnaire);

        Spinner typeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.which_spinner);
        Spinner breedSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.breed_spinner);

// ~~~ create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.pet_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dogBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.dog_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.cat_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> rabbitBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.rabbit_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> hamsterBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.hamster_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> birdBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.bird_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// ~~~ specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        typeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dogBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        catBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        rabbitBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        hamsterBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        birdBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// ~~~ apply the adapter to the spinner
        typeSpinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
       // breedSpinner.setEnabled(true);

        typeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            if(typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Dogs")) {
                breedSpinner.setAdapter(dogBreedAdapter);
            } else if(typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Cats")) {
                breedSpinner.setAdapter(catBreedAdapter);
            } else if(typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Rabbits")) {
                breedSpinner.setAdapter(rabbitBreedAdapter);
            }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        }


}
```

Working Java Code:

```
public class Questionnaire extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionnaire);

       String[] dogBreeds = {"Alsatian", "Border Collie","Labrador"};
       String[] catBreeds = {"Bombay", "British Shorthair","Persian"};
       String[] rabbitBreeds = {"Dutch", "English Lop","Flemish"};
       String[] hamsterBreeds = {"Chinese", "Russian","Syrian"};
       String[] birdBreeds = {"Parrot", "Parakeet","Cockatiel"};

        Spinner typeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.which_spinner);
        Spinner breedSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.breed_spinner);

// ~~~ create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.pet_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dogBreedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dogBreeds);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catBreedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, catBreeds);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> rabbitBreedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, rabbitBreeds);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> hamsterBreedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hamsterBreeds);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> birdBreedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, birdBreeds);

// ~~~ specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
         typeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         
// ~~~ apply the adapter to the spinner
        typeSpinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);

        typeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                switch (typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                    case "Dog":
                        dogBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(dogBreedAdapter);
                        break;

                    case "Cat":
                        catBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(catBreedAdapter);
                        break;

                    case "Rabbit":
                        rabbitBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(rabbitBreedAdapter);
                        break;

                    case "Hamster":
                        hamsterBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(hamsterBreedAdapter);
                        break;

                    case "Bird":
                        birdBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(birdBreedAdapter);
                        break;

                    default:
                        breedSpinner.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        }


}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry @Zoe- thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You Can use something like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
  if(arg0.equals(spin0)){
    spin1.setEnabled(true);
    if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("India")){
      ArrayAdapter<String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_india);
      s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spin1.setAdapter(s1);
    } 
    else if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan")) {
      ArrayAdapter <String> s2 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_pak);
      s2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spin1.setAdapter(s2);
    }
    else if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("China")) {
      ArrayAdapter <String> s3 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_china);
      s3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spin1.setAdapter(s3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me an error on the 'states_india' section (in my case dog_breeds etc), I have declared them before the onCreate, however this then crashed my emulator?

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect your suggestions, but still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Before proceeding, please note that I tried setting the default array from resources and I got an empty array. So I used this String array in this example:

```
String[] typeList = {"Dogs", "Rabbits","Cats"};
```

Let's move on:

```
final Spinner typeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.which_spinner);
        final Spinner breedSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.breed_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, typeList);
        typeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        typeSpinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
```

After setting up the previous stuff, we set an onItemSelectedListener to the typeSpinner:

```
typeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                    breedSpinner.setEnabled(true);

                    if (typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Dogs"))
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dogBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
                                                                                                     R.array.dog_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        dogBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(dogBreedAdapter);
                        
                    } else  if (typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Cats"))
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
                                                                                                     R.array.cat_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        catBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        breedSpinner.setAdapter(catBreedAdapter);
                        
                    } else  if (typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Rabbits"))
                    {
                        breedSpinner.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Edit: To use a `switch` instead of an if statement:

```
switch (typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                        case "Dogs":
                            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dogBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
                                                                                                         R.array.dog_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            dogBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            breedSpinner.setAdapter(dogBreedAdapter);
                            break;
                            
                        case "Cats":
                            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catBreedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
                                                                                                         R.array.cat_breeds, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            catBreedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            breedSpinner.setAdapter(catBreedAdapter);
                            
                            break;
                            
                        case "Rabbits":
                            breedSpinner.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                    }
```

Comment: I am not getting the same results :( I can't figure out where I am going wrong..

Comment: I figured out another way based on your reply, so thank you!